# ARIMA model in Stata

Tags: stata

I am trying to calculate in Stata a monthly autoregressive time-series measuring whether avg_happy changes with output.

For now I tried using the code:

```
arima avg_happy, ar(1) ma(1)
```

but I keep getting the error "(note:  insufficient memory or observations to estimate usual
starting values [2])
insufficient observations", even after removing some missing observations.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

My data looks like this:

```
[CODE]
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input double date float(output avg_happy) str6 country
1552           0         0 "France"
1595           0 .12514286 "France"
1626           0     .1898 "France"
1697           0 .06636364 "France"
1707           0 .07551724 "France"
1725           0 .15442307 "France"
1740           0 .15208332 "France"
1761           0 .11060607 "France"
1767           0 .07891892 "France"
1785           0 .10645833 "France"
1801           0 .14339286 "France"
1819           0 .07742424 "France"
1840           0 .16685714 "France"
1858           0 .20857143 "France"
1870           0 .07963637 "France"
1881           0  .1796923 "France"
1901           0 .09269842 "France"
1913           0     .1825 "France"
1962           0 .11526316 "France"
1972           0 .10245614 "France"
1979           0  .1946667 "France"
1989           0   .167541 "France"
2002           0  .1596875 "France"
2016           0      .146 "France"
2023           0 .11526316 "France"
2045           0  .0768421 "France"
2055           0 .22160715 "France"
2065           0 .15531915 "France"
2068           0  .0768421 "France"
2077           0 .02607143 "France"
2087           0  .0931915 "France"
2110           0 .14847457 "France"
2118           0 .06083333 "France"
2156           0 .07423729 "France"
2188           0 .10265625 "France"
2194           0 .12807018 "France"
2204 .0041370597 .10645833 "France"
2215           0 .28175437 "France"
2225           0  .1636207 "France"
2233           0 .15208332 "France"
2244           0 .26404256 "France"
2254           0  .1946667 "France"
2264           0 .28895834 "France"
2274  .007244105  .2019149 "France"
2285           0 .16946428 "France"
2294           0  .2053125 "France"
2307           0  .1932353 "France"
2316           0 .16387755 "France"
2324           0 .13978724 "France"
2367           0 .19367346 "France"
2372           0 .27872726 "France"
2381           0         . "France"
2382           0 .26756355 "France"
2389           0 .17085107 "France"
2396           0  .2830612 "France"
2400           0 .24333334 "France"
2406           0 .16649123 "France"
2415           0  .2174468 "France"
2428           0  .1798551 "France"
2433           0   .186383 "France"
2444  .005748244  .1855932 "France"
2454           0  .1361017 "France"
2463           0      .146 "France"
2468           0 .11108695 "France"
2477           0 .11918367 "France"
2508           0  .1361017 "France"
2531           0 .17929825 "France"
2541           0  .1871795 "France"
2554           0         . "France"
2555           0  .1970552 "France"
2561           0 .28565216 "France"
2577           0 .17456523 "France"
2589   .00506966    .27375 "France"
2602           0 .24333334 "France"
2616           0 .19770834 "France"
2622           0 .15869565 "France"
2633           0 .09605263 "France"
2640           0  .2329787 "France"
2651           0 .17756757 "France"
2657           0 .14129032 "France"
2672           0 .15927273 "France"
2700           0 .21291666 "France"
2728           0  .1883871 "France"
2735           0     .2555 "France"
2749           0         . "France"
2750           0 .22420147 "France"
2761           0 .31465515 "France"
2769           0     .1825 "France"
2775           0  .1795082 "France"
2782  .011836817 .13518518 "France"
2798           0 .25131148 "France"
2811           0   .167541 "France"
2815           0 .10814815 "France"
end
[/CODE]
```

Comment: Why are you using R code to show Stata data?

Comment: Hi @NickCox, sorry I just changed it to stata. Do you know what may be the issue? Thanks!

Comment: I can't interpret your dates here either. They aren't regularly spaced-and they don't have a simple interpretation as plausible Stata monthly dates for which 0 = January 1960 and so (e.g.) even recent monthly dates are much less than 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This answer refers to a previous version of the question.

**Executive summary: How is e.g. -2208988800 to be interpreted by Stata as a monthly date?**

The gap between times is evidently 86400, so at a first guess you are trying to analyse daily data using a date-time measured in seconds, given that 86400 = 24 * 60 * 60.

Dividing by 86400 yields not-too-crazy daily date values that may or may not show some other problem. For example, the data may come from other software which uses an origin for daily dates other than Stata's origin of 1 January 1960.

More than that, you describe your data as monthly, so I can't guess what else is wrong. You probably need to tell us more about the original data.

```
. mata : (-2208988800, -2208902400) :/ 86400
            1        2
    +-------------------+
  1 |  -25567   -25566  |
    +-------------------+

. mata : strofreal((-2208988800, -2208902400) :/ 86400, "%td")
               1           2
    +-------------------------+
  1 |  31dec1889   01jan1890  |
    +-------------------------+
```

To Stata, given your choice of units your dataset is, or should be, 86400 times larger than it is, which would be enormous. As it is, Stata is struggling to work with a dataset which is mostly implied gaps.

Fix your date-times to what they should be. I don't think the problem is in `arima` but rather in what you present to it.

Key information missing in your question is what you told `tsset` or `xtset`.

Comment: Great! I did the following and it worked: "generate row_number = _n
tsset row_number
arima avg_happy , ar(1) ma(1)", so the problem was that the gap between dates was too large? Thank youu!